# скрыть элемент при скроле jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!
Помогите пжлст с реализацией скрола: 
1. - скрыть если прошло время
2. - скрыть если до низа страницы осталось < 500px
код:

```js
$('#back-top').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
  });
  
       $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700) {
            $('#back-top').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#back-top").fadeOut(); }, 2000);
        } else {
            $('#back-top').fadeOut();
        }
         
          
     });
```

сейчас при таймауте работает, но периодически начинает моргать - это жутко бесит)))

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен!
методом тыка наше остановку и после уже делать затухание: `$('#back-top').fadeIn(1000).stop(true,true).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);`